# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. Student

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hello I am working on School project , I want the teacher to update the marks of the students (not eligible to edit all details) so I need another function

I am getting this error

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.
```

in web.php I have this

```
Route::put('/updatenoteevaluation/{id}', 'StudentController@updatenoteevaluation')->name('student.update');
```

and in StudentController.php I have this

```
public function updatenoteevaluation(){
    echo 'test';
}
```

As I have said I want just a function for editing specific fields so I am not going to use the default edit and update methods ,
Anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As the error says you're probably performing a GET request on a endpoint that only allows PUT. Since you're updating records it makes sense for it to be a PUT request. Review your implementation and make sure your "save/submit/whatever" request is a PUT.

Comment: The error message indicates that the request is a GET request. Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68193278/edit) the code where you execute the request to your question?

Comment: I got the erro just from the web.php part mentionned

Comment: No, you don't. You can only get this error by trying to _access_ the route. It doesn't occour when you just _define_ it. Add the code or we cannot help you. Hint: It's probably in a blade or js file.

Comment: You need to declare two routes, one GET to open the form for the teacher and another PUT/POST to do the action of updating. You are missing the GET one.

Comment: If I change put by get like this it works but I need update method so put

Comment: You are right @N69S, I think that even for other specific update I must have both edit and update (edited as needed) so It works , I am checking and I will inform you

Comment: The error  IS NOT just from the web.php, IT is because you are trying to send GET request for the route which only accepts PUT. In that case you can also define route for GET method and inside controller check if the request is get or put Route::get('/updatenoteevaluation/{', 'StudentController@updatenoteevaluation') }); or you can check if the request contains "id" or not in order to resolve the get or put !

Comment: Must pass Id in your function as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Validator`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) or custom [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) with [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic). The rules can be defined as follows:

```
[
    'field_that_must_be_present' => 'required', // or 'present'
    'field_that_must_not_be_present' => 'prohibited'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass @method('PUT') in your html form

Answer (score -1):

You have created a route that only allows the HTTP VERB PUT

see

```
Route::put
```

If you need to support GET then create a get route

```
Route::get
```

But from your logic it does make sense to use the put verb so make sure when sending your HTTP request you are using put and not get

Comment: This answer can only be considered as a comment.